# linux c++: cpu usage stats given a pthread_t

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

In a c++ program I can get a list of pthread_t identifiers and I'm trying to calculate cpu usage of each thread. If I can get the os thread id I now I can read /proc/${tid}/stat to do this; but I can't figure out how to get the os thread id given only a pthread_t to the thread.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't believe that there's a standard way to do what you're looking for.  The `pthread` library creates an abstraction over the host OS and doesn't provide a way to expose host OS-specific details.  If this is your program, you could create a mapping of `pthread_t` to the result of `gettid()` in the entry procedure for each thread.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm afraid the answer is. Unfortunately thread creation is far removed from the code I'm working on so accessing the entry function (and using gettid() or similar) may not be feasible

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511459/is-there-a-way-to-link-a-linuxs-thread-tid-and-a-pthread-t-thread-id